# Agora RTC - Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: Ignoring event undefined

Tags: agora.io

I'm currently trying to implement Agora's RTC and so far it has been working. However, there seems to be an inconsistent error that only sometimes occurs. When joining a channel with an already existing user the following error is shown and the stream is not added and consequently can't be played.

`Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: Ignoring event undefined {uid: xyz}`

In this case, *xyz* is the user id of that given existing user. I thought that it might be an issue with the code but it works sporadically and it doesn't seem to be a time lag or something like that either. Did anybody encounter this and know a solution?

Comment: Could you please specify what platform are you using. And are you joining the channel with the same uid as the uid of the existing user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ba, I was experiencing the same issue. I am not sure of the setup you are using to call certain Agora functions, but the problem I was running into was sometimes my publish local stream function would be called before Agora was done capturing the user's media. I found this error in the console accompanied with "No track in stream" or something close to that. My fix was to ensure that the Agora init() function, which captures the user's media, completed before calling for the local stream to publish.